# Selecting several class properties in one query

Tags: c#, linq

The following code takes a collection of class C and creates a collection consisting of the values of two properties A and B. A and B are put inside the same collection:

```
class A
{
    public int x { get; set; }
}
class B
{
    public int x { get; set; }
}
class C
{
    public A A { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
}

..........

var items = new List<C>()
                {
                    new C()
                        {
                            A = new A() {x = 1},
                            B = new B() {x = 2}
                        },
                    new C()
                        {
                            A = new A() {x = 3},
                            B = new B() {x = 4}
                        },
                };

var qA = from item in items
         select (object)item.A;
var qB = from item in items
         select (object)item.B;
var qAll = qA.Concat(qB);
```

Is it possible to do this with one query?

Comment: is `items` an `IList<C>`?  why do you cast `item.A` and `item.B` to `object`?

Comment: Yes. items is IList<C>. I have updated the code now. I'm casting A and B to object, so I can put them inside one collection. The real code doesn't do that, I use an interface which both A and B inherit from, but it is not important. The code in the question is just to demonstrate the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to flatten properties like that, you can feed arrays to [SelectMany()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx):

```
var qAll = items.SelectMany(item => new object[] { item.A, item.B });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ForEach:

```
var qAll = new List<object>();
items.ForEach(item => { qAll.Add(item.A); qAll.Add(item.B) });
```

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment, I guess. Sorry to for the disappointment. Just trying to accomplish the one query request.